# Set in Makefile the value of a variable previously set in via included file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile` that includes a `.env` file, and this `.env` sets default value of some variables. One of the variables default has relative path to file. In Makefile I want to obtain the full path, because this variable could be passed via command line (hence, bypassing .env's value) and I want to make sure I have use it as full path.

What I tried:

.env file

```
FILE := relative/path/to/file
```

Makefile file

```
include .env
export

FILE := $(shell realpath $(FILE))

.PHONY: sometarget
sometarget:
    @echo "FILE = $(FILE)"
```

I also tried to replace the assignment operator to `=`, `?=` and others, but all failed.

I expected to achieve FILE as /full/path/to/file.

EDIT:

Updated to add a sample target to the `Makefile` to use as example.

Also, to add that I learned that actually the issue is when passing the value via command line, e.g. `make FILE=relative`. In this particular case is that I get simply "relative" as output when I expected its full path. That's my main issue.

Comment: It's working for me when I print value of `FILE` in recipe, how are you using it?

Comment: You didn't show us what you ran and what result you got.

Comment: Right. Looks like my previous assumptions were incorrect. The value is overwritten, but not when I run `make FILE=relative` -- I never get its realpath, I only get FILE as "relative"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [override](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html):

```
include .env
override FILE := $(shell realpath $(FILE))

$(info Here $$FILE is [${FILE}])

all:
        @echo '$$FILE' in recipe $(FILE)
```